# Set the bottom right of a spritefont in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

Well I have been trying to set the position of a spritefont based on the bottom right corner, however, it is way off when I set it, I will set it to 10,10 and I wont even seen it, if I set it to 40,40 I just start to be able to see the bottom right corner...I think I am doing it right...Here is my code:

```
public void DrawFont(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.DrawString(gameFont, fontText, fontPos, fontColor);
    }
```

fontPos is the upper left corner. And this is in its own class. Then I have another method (in the same class):

```
public void setBottomRight(Vector2 newVector2)
    {
        fontPos.X = newVector2.X - gameFont.MeasureString(fontText).X;
        fontPos.Y = newVector2.Y - gameFont.MeasureString(fontText).Y;
    }
```

And I use this in the update method of the Game.cs class and set the vector to a new vector at 10,10 but I am not able to see the text, I checked to see if it was just a gap in my text, and it was not.

I feel that this is right...or did I make a dumb mistake...? Or does the MeaureString method just not provide the length from edge to edge?

Thanks!

Comment: The height is always the same and equal to the line height. If its a large font the gap between you characters and the bottom of the font may be large.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? Are you trying to get the text to draw in the bottom-right corner of the screen?

Comment: Where and how do you call your setBottomRight method?

Comment: The math looks right. Be sure your fontText string is not empty when measuring. Depending on the size of your font, why should you see more than the bottom corner at 10,10? If you draw a string with its bottom right corner in the top left corner of the screen it will of course be mostly cut off. At 10,10 I wouldn't expect to see much at all unless your font size is tiny.

Answer (score 1):

Your original logic is almost sound. The only thing not being correct is the Measurestring Y value.
The Y-value of the measurestring returns double the vertical size of the string. So if you have size 14 as a string it will return 28. Meaning that instead of giving you the height it will have given you double that ammount throwing your string of the screen.
replacing

```
fontPos.Y = newVector2.Y - gameFont.MeasureString(fontText).Y;
```

with

```
fontPos.Y = newVector2.Y - gameFont.MeasureString(fontText).Y/2;
```

will solve your problems!

Comment: That works if I have my font size set to 12, but I drew a mark on the screen with its top left at 100, 100, and used that code to set my fonts bottom right to 100,100, and the font is slightly lower than the mark I drew...The font size is 72, and ideas on why it wont work? (The X axis is fine)